# Adding buttons to windowmanager

Tags: android

I wanna make a lock screen app and I use Overlay window. But what should I do if I want to add some buttons to my window manager.And which command I should use after that time when user had pressed button?

My code:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int densityDpi = (int)(metrics.density * 160f);
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        mTopView = (RelativeLayout) li.inflate(R.layout.red_layout, null, false);
int LayoutParamFlags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS;

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                densityDpi * 4,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                LayoutParamFlags,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        windowManager.addView(mTopView,params);
```

Thank you.